# Popover a date string and show it on a calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a little info box on my site where i use several popover to show detailed information about the selection. For example i have a string with a name and a popover with the picture of this person.

Now i have a string with a date and i want to show this date on a calendar on a popover.

I have a little Mockup what shows what i want:

[image: Mockup for calendar plugin]

I searched a lot on google to find a plugin for this but i does not found anything.

Does anyone know such a jQuery/ Javascript Plugin what i looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with [jQuery DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?  You can set it so the user can't change the date fairly easily.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know that i can disable the select function. I'll try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap Datepicker, you can assign to the span elements the events to open the Datepicker control.

Like this:

**HTML**

```
<span class="aDate">1/1/2014</span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.aDate').datepicker();
```

With that, you can bind it with the events you need (click, hover, etc)

Comment: Nice idea with the Bootstrap datepicker but your code doesn't work to me. It doesn't show the date when i try it. Any ideas how it works correctly?

Comment: [Here](http://kenyontechnology.com/2013/10/08/datepicker-for-bootstrap-with-twitter-bootstrap-3-0/) is how it works in bootstrap 3.